# Adding a function to lists and calling them in C#

Tags: c#, lua

To help me learn c#, I am converting a script I made in lua to C#

I want to know if it is possible to add a function to a list (table in lua) and call it

Here's what I have in Lua

```
functions{ function() print("Hello World!") end }
functions[1]()

Output: Hello World!
```

In C# I am using Lists
Example

```
var functions = new List</* What do I put here */>();
functions.Add(/* Somehow define a public static void here */);
```

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder why you'd need something like this, moreso as a beginner. This will probably break more principles and design rules that I could name. Are you using this to avoid using objects? C# is not a scripting language like LUA, it's an OO language.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Func<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) depending whether you need result or not, use [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to define function in style you are looking for:

```
var functions = new List<Action>();
functions.Add(() => { Console.WriteLine("Here!"); }
functions[0]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! Well, I can't say with certainty that this is the *best* answer, but it's my take on the this situation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var functions = new List<Action>();
        functions.Add(new Action(delegate
        {
            // Do stuff
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully did stuff.");
        }));
        functions[0].DynamicInvoke();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Actions in .NET are used a lot with the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).